# How to create an php extension that will include a php file

Tags: php, php-extension

I need to build an PHP extension that will include a PHP file. I have read [Extension Writing Part I: Introduction to PHP and Zend](http://devzone.zend.com/303/extension-writing-part-i-introduction-to-php-and-zend/) and understand how to create an PHP extension with C.

But I could not include a PHP file.

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif
#include "php.h"
#include "php_hello.h"

static zend_function_entry hello_functions[] = {
    PHP_FE(hello_world, NULL)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};

zend_module_entry hello_module_entry = {
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 20010901
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
#endif
    PHP_HELLO_WORLD_EXTNAME,
    hello_functions,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 20010901
    PHP_HELLO_WORLD_VERSION,
#endif
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

#ifdef COMPILE_DL_HELLO
ZEND_GET_MODULE(hello)
#endif

PHP_FUNCTION(hello_world)
{
    char *name;
    int name_len;
    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "s", &name, &name_len) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_NULL();
    }

    php_require_once(name); // <-- is this possible?
    //RETURN_STRING("Hello World", 1);
}
```

I have also tried the PHP-CPP but that will required some dependency install, which is not possible on the shared hosting I use.

as @Karoly Horvath said, i have used "call_user_function_ex" but it's shows Fatal error:  Function call failed

here is my complete code

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include "config.h"
#endif
#include "php.h"
#include "php_hello.h"
#define functionNameStr "require_once"

static zend_function_entry hello_functions[] = {
    PHP_FE(hello_world, NULL)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};

zend_module_entry hello_module_entry = {
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 20010901
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
#endif
    PHP_HELLO_WORLD_EXTNAME,
    hello_functions,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
#if ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >= 20010901
    PHP_HELLO_WORLD_VERSION,
#endif
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

#ifdef COMPILE_DL_HELLO
ZEND_GET_MODULE(hello)
#endif

PHP_FUNCTION(hello_world)
{
    char *name;
    int name_len;
    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "s", &name, &name_len) == FAILURE) {
        RETURN_NULL();
    }   

    zval *function_name, *retval_ptr, *param_val, **params[1];

    TSRMLS_FETCH();

    MAKE_STD_ZVAL(function_name);
    ZVAL_STRINGL(function_name, functionNameStr,
            strlen(functionNameStr), 0);

    MAKE_STD_ZVAL(param_val);
    ZVAL_STRINGL(param_val, name,
            strlen(name), 0);

    params[0] = &param_val;

    if (call_user_function_ex(CG(function_table), NULL, function_name,
            &retval_ptr, 1, params, 0, NULL TSRMLS_CC) != SUCCESS) {
        php_printf("%s",name);
        zend_error(E_ERROR, "Function call failed");
        RETURN_NULL();

    }else{
        php_printf("%s","SUCCESS");
    }

    FREE_ZVAL(function_name);
    FREE_ZVAL(param_val);

}
```

Comment: Just wondering why you would want this (curiosity ;-) )

Comment: `call_user_function_ex` ?

Comment: @Marien i have made a php encoder with c to create and maintain licence, you can have look [In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0gxszLPt-SA)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath i have update the questions with your solution but its show fatal error.

Comment: Sry, I don't have an environment to test it...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath thank you so much, now its working on many 5.5 shared hosting.